Network Communication
I a working with Raspberry pi 3 model b+.
It has 2 network interfaces 1. Ethernet 2. Access Point

The raspberry pi has to communicate with PC and ESP32 simultaneously.
How it can transfer data received from PC to ESP and vice versa ?
Suggestions are highly appreciated.

What OS? What network manager? What "data"? If the ESP are networked why doesn't the PC access them directly? If you have an Access Point why (and how) is it on the same subnet as Ethernet?

please do not post pictures of text ... post the text instead, format as code for readability

tried that way , didn't get expected outcome so used the easy approach.
